# Оформление прямой речи (2)

Tags: прямая-речь

Вопрос, собственно, следующий: может ли прямая речь вводится предложением, которое само по себе уже является самостоятельным. Иными словами, можно ли после такого предложения поставить двоеточие и все-таки привести высказывание, которое к нему относится?

Например:

Аналитики резюмируют сообщение словами о том, что объем производства к концу года не вырастет, а останется на уровне начала кризиса: «Когда уровень реальных доходов населения стабилизируется и вырастет спрос, объем импорта, скорее всего, снова вырастет».

Или:

Он считает, что импортозамещение уже заработало и т. д.: а далее приводится обоснование его мнения другими словами, то есть это уже не то высказывание, которое содержится в авторских словах, а просто продолжение его мысли.

Конечно, с одной стороны, кроме двоеточия между этими двумя предложениями вряд ли что поставишь: они ведь связаны между собой. Но с другой стороны, ведь это не авторские слова, вводящие прямую речь. Собственно, самый глупый вопрос: допустимо ли поставить точку, а само высказывание дать отдельным предложением в кавычках?

Comment: Аленка, прямая речь может начинаться новым предложением. Но чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, необходимо видеть само предложение, иначе ответ может развернуться на целые дискуссии.

Comment: Исправила в вопросе то предложение, которое наиболее сомнительно.

Answer (score 2):

Аналитики резюмируют сообщение словами о том, что объем производства к концу года не вырастет, а останется на уровне начала кризиса: «Когда уровень реальных доходов населения стабилизируется и вырастет спрос, объем импорта, скорее всего, снова вырастет».

В данном примере знаки препинания расставлены верно, но смысл предложения неясен, так как информация первой части (слов автора) не соотносится с информацией второй части (прямой речи), а **они должны быть связаны**.

В первой части **суждение высказывается обобщенно**, а во второй -  **более конкретно, с использованием авторской стилистики речи**, например:

Аналитики прогнозируют  роста импорта только при увеличении реальной покупательной способности: «Когда уровень реальных доходов населения стабилизируется и вырастет спрос, объем импорта, скорее всего, снова вырастет».

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, двоеточие здесь неуместно, поскольку здесь нет слов, вводящих прямую речь. Но чтобы было ясно, что это именно авторские слова,  можно после кавычек добавить слова: "поясняют аналитики", "заявляют аналитики" и т.д.